# finding good C and gamma parameters for SVR in libsvm

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

Hi everybody I have difficulties using SVR in libsvm.
I am following all steps for finding best C and gamma parameter by using grid.py but the accuracy rate still quite low, around 0.1. But when I tried using cross validation the accuracy is 0.99. I'm still finding a way to improve the accuracy rate.
Because I'm using svr the accuracy that I'm talking about here is squared correlation coefficient value. 
My data contain 30 x 5 predictors and 30 x 1 predicted value (data label).
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

What I've tried:

Finding the best `C` and `g` values:

```
tools/grid.py train.txt.scale
```

and I got: `C = 16`, `g = 0.008`

Run 30-fold cross validation (I want to use leave one out cross validation) with the best `C` and `g` values:

```
svm-train -v 30 -c 16 -g 0.008 train.txt
```

I got:

Cross Validation Mean squared error = 6.62503
Cross Validation Squared correlation coefficient = 0.38175

But on `svmpredict`, I got 0.103281159524459 accuracy.

It seem this are common methods in libsvm to find best `C` and `g` values. I just really don't know if there's any hope to improve this accuracy to 0.8 or higher.

Comment: I'm not following, are you performing classification or regression? We measure classification performance by accuracy, and regression by mean-squared error

Comment: oh sorry. Yes I mean the accuracy that I talking about is the square correlation coefficient from the regression